# How to write a Strings data to a text file - Java

Tags: java

I have this account creation program I'm working on, and would love to save the persons name, last name, email and password to a text file. The following snippet *should* do just that, but the error message I'm getting when I put a String variable in the .write method is, **"no suitable method found for write(JTextFeild)".**

```
private void signupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    fname.getText();
    lname.getText();
    email.getText();
    reemail.getText();
    password.getText();
    repassword.getText();

    if(male.equals(true)) {
        males = true;
    }
    if(female.equals(true)) {
        females = true;
    }

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("UserPass.txt"));
        writer.write(fname);

    }
    catch ( IOException e) {
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if ( writer != null) {
                writer.close( );
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to get the text from the JTextField as a String. Call `getText()` on it.

Comment: If `male` and `female` are also form fields (such as checkboxes), the `male.equals(true)` also won't work for similar reasons. Need to extract the value as `boolean` there, too.

Comment: Thanks guys, this really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `getText()` in javax.swing.text.JTextComponent:

> public **String** getText()

JTextField is just the GUI element, `getText()` doesn't change it.
You should store the result in a String variable and then use it to `write()`.